# Pass a keyword argument to a decorator python

Tags: python-3.x, closures, decorator, keyword-argument

I have a wrapper function, like this:

```
def check(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        while 1:
            try:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            except AssertionError:
                print('Invalid Input')
            except ValueError:
                print('Invalid Input')
    return wrap
```

However I want to make the error input customizable.
I tried this:

```
def check(func, errorText='Invalid Input’):...
```

Using it like this:

```
@check(errorText = 'Input must be in {}'.format(tiles))
```

And got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    @check(errorText = 'Input must be in {}'.format(tiles))
TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: ‘func'
```

I tried this:

```
...
def wrap(*args, errorText = ‘Invalid Input’, **kwargs):
...
```

And got no error, but it still printed `Invalid Input` as the error message.

Here is some of the code I am using:

```
@check
def getInt(_min, _max, _type, errorText = ’Number is not in correct range'):
    n = int(input("Enter {} number (inbetween {} and {}): ".format(_type, _min, _max)))
    assert _min <= n <= _max
    return n

@check
def setAt(board, new, errorText = ’Space is already filled.'):
    row = getInt(1, 5, 'row')-1
    col = getInt(1, 5, 'column')-1
    assert board[row][col] == '.'
    board[row][col] = new

@check
def getTile(errorText = ‘Input must be in {}’.format(tiles)):
    tile = input("Enter tile to choose: ").upper()
    assert tile in tiles
    return tile
```

Comment: Do you understand what a decorator does?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I guess not...What should I use?